# Is it possible to convert Windows Phone App project into Windows Phone Class Library?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I accidentally created a Windows Phone App project instead of Windows Phone Class Library project and worked on it for few days, till I realized that when I'm running the "end-point" application it installs the "library" as an app as well.

So is it possible to convert Windows Phone App project into Windows Phone Class Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily the solution was very easy. 
Instead of creating new Windows Phone Class Library project and manually moving files into it, 
I modified the `Project.csproj`:

1) Close Visual Studio 
2) Change `SilverlightApplication` tag to `false` 
3) Remove tags:
`SupportedCultures`
`XapOutputs`
`GenerateSilverlightManifest`
`XapFilename`
`SilverlightManifestTemplate`
`SilverlightAppEntry`
4) Open VS and clean the project

That's it!

P.S.: Tested on WP7.1 & VS2012